# How Do I Remove flickering when selecting an area in WinForms / C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using WinForms/C# to develop simple applications.After much research, I am not able to get rid of significant flickering. Here is what I am trying to do:

- Pain an image in a background panel (the image does not change after loading)
- Select an area of the image through dragging a rectangular area on a second panel on top of the image.
  The image panel is a child of the form, and the drag panel is a child of the image panel. The example provided is a simplification of the two-panel approach I need to select/drag objects.

I have done extensive research on this topic, and although I am able to minimize the problem with timer-based / two-buffer approaches, I do not understand why I cannot make the two-panel approach work. Any help is greatly appreciated. For example, I am only using the refresh/Paint event to paint, setting "DoubleBuffered" on the form and overriding "CreateParams" as some other users have suggested.

Here is the self-contained program that demonstrates the issue (NOTE: set the proper path for the image to be displayed "_image_filename" on your local computer); if you create a new project, just overwrite the default cs program with the content below. The resizing methods are there to prevent the window from being resized. Thanks for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace TESTING
{
  
  public class TEST_PROGRAM
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      try { Application.Run(new TEST_FORM()); }
      catch { }
    }
  }

  public class TEST_FORM : Form
  {
    // Client area definition.
    private Size _minimum_client_size = new Size(800, 600);
    private Size _client_size_offset;
    // Application font.
    private Font _font;
    // Drawing panels.
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel _image_panel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel _drag_panel;
    // Image.
    private string _image_filename = "C:\\image.jpg";
    private Bitmap _image_bitmap;
    // Dragging support.
    private Rectangle _drag_selection_area;
    private Point _drag_initial_mouse_location;
    private bool _drag_is_ongoing;

    //===========================================================================
    public TEST_FORM()
    {
      // Start building form.
      this.SuspendLayout();
      this._client_size_offset = this.Size - this.ClientSize;
      this.ClientSize = this._minimum_client_size;
      this.Resize += this._OnResizeHandler;
      this.MaximizeBox = false;
      this.MinimizeBox = true;
      this.Name = "TestForm";
      this.Text = "Test Form";
      this._font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
      this.Font = this._font;
      this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Honeydew;
      this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
      // Enable doublebuffering.
      this.DoubleBuffered = false;
      this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
      this.ResumeLayout(true);
      this.PerformLayout();
      // Add image panel
      this._image_panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
      if (this._image_panel == null)
        throw new Exception("Unable to create image panel");
      this._image_panel.Left = this.ClientRectangle.X + 4;
      this._image_panel.Top = this.ClientRectangle.Y + 4;
      this._image_panel.Width = this.ClientRectangle.Width - 8;
      this._image_panel.Height = this.ClientRectangle.Height - 8;
      this._image_panel.Font = this.Font;
      this._image_panel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
      this._image_panel.Text = "";
      this._image_panel.Paint += this._ImagePanelPaintHandler;
      // Add drag panel.
      this._drag_panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
      if (this._drag_panel == null)
        throw new Exception("Unable to create drag panel");
      this._drag_panel.Left = this.ClientRectangle.X + 4;
      this._drag_panel.Top = this.ClientRectangle.Y + 4;
      this._drag_panel.Width = this.ClientRectangle.Width - 8;
      this._drag_panel.Height = this.ClientRectangle.Height - 8;
      this._drag_panel.Font = this.Font;
      this._drag_panel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
      this._drag_panel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
      this._drag_panel.Paint += this._DragPanelPaintHandler;
      this._drag_panel.MouseDown += this._OnMouseDownDragHandler;
      this._drag_panel.MouseMove += this._OnMouseMoveDragHandler;
      this._drag_panel.MouseUp += this._OnMouseUpDragHandler;
      // Add image panel to form.
      this.Controls.Add(this._image_panel);
      this._image_panel.Show();
      // Add drag panel to image panel.
      this._image_panel.Controls.Add(this._drag_panel);
      this._drag_panel.Show();
      // Define image file.
      if (!File.Exists(this._image_filename))
        throw new Exception("Selected image does not exists");
      // Display image.
      this._image_panel.Refresh();
    }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
      get
      {
        CreateParams handleParam = base.CreateParams;
        handleParam.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED       
        return handleParam;
      }
    }
    private void _ImagePanelPaintHandler(Object source, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      if (this._image_bitmap == null)
      {
        // Load image file into bitmap.
        System.Drawing.Image image = Image.FromFile(this._image_filename);
        if (image == null) throw new Exception("Unable to load image");
        double x_ratio = (double)image.Width / (double)this._image_panel.Width;
        double y_ratio = (double)image.Height / (double)this._image_panel.Height;
        double ratio = (x_ratio > y_ratio) ? x_ratio : y_ratio;
        this._image_bitmap = new Bitmap(image,
          new Size((int)((double)image.Width / ratio), (int)((double)image.Height / ratio)));
        if (this._image_bitmap == null) throw new Exception("Unable to create bitmap");
        image.Dispose();
      }
      if (this._image_bitmap != null)
      {
        // Paint bitmap.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this._image_bitmap,
          (this._image_panel.ClientRectangle.Width - this._image_bitmap.Width) / 2,
          (this._image_panel.ClientRectangle.Height - this._image_bitmap.Height) / 2,
          this._image_bitmap.Width, this._image_bitmap.Height);
      }
    }
    private void _DragPanelPaintHandler(Object source, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      if ((this._drag_selection_area.Width > 0) && (this._drag_selection_area.Height > 0))
      {
        SolidBrush highlight_brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 255, 255));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(highlight_brush, this._drag_selection_area);
      }
    }
    private void _OnMouseDownDragHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      Point mouse_location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
      this._drag_selection_area = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
      this._drag_initial_mouse_location = mouse_location;
      this._drag_is_ongoing = true;
      this._drag_panel.Refresh();
    }
    private void _OnMouseMoveDragHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      if (this._drag_is_ongoing)
      {
        Point mouse_location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
        this._drag_selection_area.Width = mouse_location.X - this._drag_initial_mouse_location.X;
        this._drag_selection_area.Height = mouse_location.Y - this._drag_initial_mouse_location.Y;
        this._drag_panel.Refresh();
      }
    }
    private void _OnMouseUpDragHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      if (this._drag_is_ongoing)
      {
        Point mouse_location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
        this._drag_selection_area.Width = mouse_location.X - this._drag_initial_mouse_location.X;
        this._drag_selection_area.Height = mouse_location.Y - this._drag_initial_mouse_location.Y;
        this._drag_panel.Refresh();
        this._drag_is_ongoing = false;
      }
    }
    private void _OnResizeHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Control control = sender as Control;
      if (control.ClientSize != this._minimum_client_size)
        control.Size = this._minimum_client_size + this._client_size_offset;
    }
    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnLayout(e);
      this.MinimumSize = this.MinimumClientSize + this._client_size_offset;
    }
    public Size MinimumClientSize
    {
      get { return this._minimum_client_size; }
      set
      {
        this._minimum_client_size = value;
        this.PerformLayout();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If all you want to do is draw a non-flickering selection rectangle, use [ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe). You draw it once to show it, an draw it a second time (with exactly the same coordinates) to erase it

Comment: And do not use `Refresh`. Just call `Invalidate` and let the UI repaint itself during the regular WM_PAINT session.

Comment: I am able to draw the selection area but I can still see the flickering - but I am still using the refresh, so I still need to try with Invalidate. I did some testing with WPF, and I can drag items & overlay selection areas without any problem (no flickering). So I am thinking of switching to WPF! The main problem with WPF is that Camtasia (which I use to extract sub-windows & illustrate documentation) does not see any canvas objects (with WinForms, Camtasia can capture panels without any problems).

Answer (score 0):

Jiri, Thank you for your answer - I made the changes you suggest and it works great! I am posting the code below for others (create a new .NET 4.8 WinForm project / replace all default .cs programs with the self-contained code below).

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace TESTING
{
  // NOTE: set the proper path for the image to be displayed (_image_filename).
  public class TEST_PROGRAM
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      try { Application.Run(new TEST_FORM()); }
      catch { }
    }
  }
  public class MyPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
  {
    public MyPanel()
    {
      this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
  }

  public class TEST_FORM : Form
  {
    // Client area definition.
    private Size _minimum_client_size = new Size(800, 600);
    private Size _client_size_offset;
    // Drawing panels.
    private MyPanel _image_panel;
    private MyPanel _drag_panel;
    // Image.
    private string _image_filename = "C:\\image.jpg";
    private Bitmap _image_bitmap;
    // Dragging support.
    private Rectangle _drag_selection_area;
    private Point _drag_initial_mouse_location;
    private bool _drag_is_ongoing;

    
   
 //===========================================================================
    public TEST_FORM()
    {
      // Start building form.
      this.SuspendLayout();
      this._client_size_offset = this.Size - this.ClientSize;
      this.ClientSize = this._minimum_client_size;
      this.Resize += this._OnResizeHandler;
      this.MaximizeBox = false;
      this.MinimizeBox = true;
      this.Name = "TestForm";
      this.Text = "Test Form";
      this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Honeydew;
      this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
      // Enable doublebuffering on the form.
      this.DoubleBuffered = true;
      this.ResumeLayout(true);
      this.PerformLayout();
      // Add image panel
      this._image_panel = new MyPanel();
      if (this._image_panel == null)
        throw new Exception("Unable to create image panel");
      this._image_panel.Left = this.ClientRectangle.X + 4;
      this._image_panel.Top = this.ClientRectangle.Y + 4;
      this._image_panel.Width = this.ClientRectangle.Width - 8;
      this._image_panel.Height = this.ClientRectangle.Height - 8;
      this._image_panel.Font = this.Font;
      this._image_panel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
      this._image_panel.Text = "";
      this._image_panel.Paint += this._ImagePanelPaintHandler;
      // Add drag panel (on top of image panel).
      this._drag_panel = new MyPanel();
      if (this._drag_panel == null)
        throw new Exception("Unable to create drag panel");
      this._drag_panel.Left = this.ClientRectangle.X + 4;
      this._drag_panel.Top = this.ClientRectangle.Y + 4;
      this._drag_panel.Width = this.ClientRectangle.Width - 8;
      this._drag_panel.Height = this.ClientRectangle.Height - 8;
      this._drag_panel.Font = this.Font;
      this._drag_panel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
      this._drag_panel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
      this._drag_panel.Paint += this._DragPanelPaintHandler;
      this._drag_panel.MouseDown += this._OnMouseDownDragHandler;
      this._drag_panel.MouseMove += this._OnMouseMoveDragHandler;
      this._drag_panel.MouseUp += this._OnMouseUpDragHandler;
      // Add image panel to form.
      this.Controls.Add(this._image_panel);
      this._image_panel.Show();
      // Add drag panel to image panel.
      this._image_panel.Controls.Add(this._drag_panel);
      this._drag_panel.Show();
      // Check that image file.
      if (!File.Exists(this._image_filename))
        throw new Exception("Selected image does not exists");
      // Display image.
      this._image_panel.Refresh();
    }
    private void _ImagePanelPaintHandler(Object source, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      if (this._image_bitmap == null)
      {
        // Load image file into bitmap.
        System.Drawing.Image image = Image.FromFile(this._image_filename);
        if (image == null) throw new Exception("Unable to load image");
        double x_ratio = (double)image.Width / (double)this._image_panel.Width;
        double y_ratio = (double)image.Height / (double)this._image_panel.Height;
        double ratio = (x_ratio > y_ratio) ? x_ratio : y_ratio;
        this._image_bitmap = new Bitmap(image,
          new Size((int)((double)image.Width / ratio), (int)((double)image.Height / ratio)));
        if (this._image_bitmap == null) throw new Exception("Unable to create bitmap");
        image.Dispose();
      }
      if (this._image_bitmap != null)
      {
        // Paint bitmap.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this._image_bitmap,
          (this._image_panel.ClientRectangle.Width - this._image_bitmap.Width) / 2,
          (this._image_panel.ClientRectangle.Height - this._image_bitmap.Height) / 2,
          this._image_bitmap.Width, this._image_bitmap.Height);
      }
    }
    private void _DragPanelPaintHandler(Object source, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      if ((this._drag_selection_area.Width > 0) && (this._drag_selection_area.Height > 0))
      {
        SolidBrush highlight_brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 255, 255));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(highlight_brush, this._drag_selection_area);
      }
    }
    private void _OnMouseDownDragHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      Point mouse_location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
      this._drag_selection_area = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
      this._drag_initial_mouse_location = mouse_location;
      this._drag_is_ongoing = true;
    }
    private void _OnMouseMoveDragHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      if (this._drag_is_ongoing)
      {
        Point mouse_location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
        this._drag_selection_area.Width = mouse_location.X - this._drag_initial_mouse_location.X;
        this._drag_selection_area.Height = mouse_location.Y - this._drag_initial_mouse_location.Y;
        this._drag_panel.Refresh();
      }
    }
    private void _OnMouseUpDragHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      if (this._drag_is_ongoing)
      {
        Point mouse_location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
        this._drag_selection_area.Width = mouse_location.X - this._drag_initial_mouse_location.X;
        this._drag_selection_area.Height = mouse_location.Y - this._drag_initial_mouse_location.Y;
        this._drag_panel.Refresh();
        this._drag_is_ongoing = false;
      }
    }
    // To prevent form from being resized.
    private void _OnResizeHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // To prevent form from being resized.
      Control control = sender as Control;
      if (control.ClientSize != this._minimum_client_size)
        control.Size = this._minimum_client_size + this._client_size_offset;
    }
    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
      // To prevent form from being resized.
      base.OnLayout(e);
      this.MinimumSize = this.MinimumClientSize + this._client_size_offset;
    }
    public Size MinimumClientSize
    {
      // To prevent form from being resized.
      get { return this._minimum_client_size; }
      set
      {
        this._minimum_client_size = value;
        this.PerformLayout();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I realize that the code is not efficient (it repaints the whole image), but eliminating the flickering was the main objective. The desired behavior is not to highlight the selection area, but to highlight the region surrounding the selection area, which can cover most of the image when the selection area is small.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Derive your own panel and set the DoubleBuffer property to true in the constructor:

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Then use this panel for both _image_panel and _drag_panel:

```
this._image_panel = new MyPanel();
// ...
this._drag_panel = new MyPanel();
```

That should do the trick.

Alternatively, if you don't want to derive a new class just for setting the value of the DoubleBuffer property, you can create an extension using reflection:

```
public static class ControlExtension
{
    public static void SetDoubleBuffered(this Control c, bool value)
    {
        typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)?.SetValue(c, value);
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
_image_panel.SetDoubleBuffered(true);
_drag_panel.SetDoubleBuffered(true);
```

However, your code is pretty inefficient - you always redraw the whole image. You should avoid as much rendering as possible. At first, replace Refresh() with Invalidate(). Then, calculate regions (rectangles) that really need to be redrawn, and replace Invalidate() with Invalidate(Rectangle), to invalidate only them.

You can also remove the CreateParams override and the line that starts with "this.SetStyle(".